# How to check if ray don`t intersect the face more

Tags: javascript, three.js, intersection

I create cubes and rectangles on my scene with userData, that have 6 parameters "false". From every face i cast a ray and if it intersect face from other object, this face became "true". All works very well, but i cant to chenge this parameter back to "false" if ray don`t intersect this face more

**Piece of my code**

```
box.userData.sides = {
                    0: false,
                    1: false,
                    2: false,
                    3: false,
                    4: false,
                    5: false
                }


            collision.push(box);
            scene.add(box);

            checkRaycast();


}


load(0, 0, 0, 'cube', 0, 0, 0);

function checkRaycast() {
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var intersects = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < collision.length; j++) {

        var pos = collision[j].geometry.attributes.position; 
        var ori = new THREE.Vector3();
        var dir = new THREE.Vector3();
        var a = new THREE.Vector3(),
            b = new THREE.Vector3(),
            c = new THREE.Vector3(),
            tri = new THREE.Triangle();

        var index = collision[j].geometry.index;    
        var faces = index.count / 3;
        scene.updateMatrixWorld()
        for (let i = 0; i < faces; i++) {
            a.fromBufferAttribute(pos, index.array[i * 3 + 0]);
            b.fromBufferAttribute(pos, index.array[i * 3 + 1]);
            c.fromBufferAttribute(pos, index.array[i * 3 + 2]);
            a.set(a.x + collision[j].position.x, a.y + collision[j].position.y, a.z + collision[j].position.z);
            b.set(b.x + collision[j].position.x, b.y + collision[j].position.y, b.z + collision[j].position.z);
            c.set(c.x + collision[j].position.x, c.y + collision[j].position.y, c.z + collision[j].position.z);
            tri.set(a, b, c);
            tri.getMidpoint(ori);
            tri.getNormal(dir);

            raycaster.set(ori, dir);    

            intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(collision, true);

            //scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(dir, ori, 500, 0xff0000));
            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                var intFace = Math.floor(intersects[0].faceIndex / 2);
                if (intersects[0].distance > 0 && intersects[0].distance < 0.2) {
                    intersects[0].object.userData.sides[intFace] = true;
                }
            } // this works but with all sides. I need to check if ray don`t intersect specific side more
              else {

                    collision[j].userData.sides[0] = false;
                    collision[j].userData.sides[1] = false;
                    collision[j].userData.sides[2] = false;
                    collision[j].userData.sides[3] = false;
                    collision[j].userData.sides[4] = false;
                    collision[j].userData.sides[5] = false;

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i add this code to render function all works fine

```
for (let j = 0; j < collision.length; j++) 
{ 
    for (let k = 0; k < 6; k++) 
    {    
       collision[j].userData.sides[k] = false;  
    }   
}
```